# Alias for git commands

Tags: command-line, git, alias

Most of the time, I use these `git` commands :

- `git add src/ package.json`
- `git commit -m "custom message"`
- `git push origin "name_of_the_branch"`

So I want to make a single alias command which should look like:

```
git_alias src/ package.json && "custom message" && name_of_the_branch
```

By running the above alias, it should run all three `git` commands (`add`, `commit` and `push`).

How can I do this?

**Note**

I know that I can make alias for any command (in this case, `git commit`) as follows:

```
alias gc='git commit -m '
```

Comment: Note that if the intent is to explicitly commit _only_ changes in `src/` and `package.json`, then you can do `git commit -m "..." src/ package.json`. You don't need to add them beforehand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you need to make a function. Add the following snippet to your `~/.bash_aliases`:

```bash
# Function for custom Git command (will only work for single files)
_git_commit_push() {
    git add "$1" && \
    git commit -m "$2" && \
    git push origin "$3"
}

alias gc='_git_commit_push'
```

Now, when you reload your Bash config, this function and alias should be defined.

Notice the three parameters: `$1`, `$2` and `$3`. These are the command line arguments for your function. Also note that the expression `&& \` *(logical AND plus escaping the line break)* will only run the subsequent command if the first command is run.

Now you can run your function (or the alias `gc`) with three arguments corresponding to the three strings (package name, custom message and name of branch). Make sure that all arguments containing spaces are enclosed in quotes, like this:

```
gc "src/ package.json any_other_file" "This is my commit message" main
```

You could also add some sanity checks, for instance that the files you want to add exists: 
*(Now modified to accommodate multiple files as argument `$1`)*

```bash
# Function for custom Git command (will work for multiple files as argument $1)
_git_commit_push() {
    # Split first argument into array
    read -a filelist <<< "$1"

    # Iterate over array of files
    for file in "${filelist[@]}"
    do
        # Test if the file $file does NOT (!) exist (-e)
        if [[ ! -e "$file" ]]
        # This is what happens when the file DOES NOT exist
        then
            echo "Error: The file $file does not exist!"
            return 1 # Exit function with error code 1
        # This is what happens when the file DOES exist
        else
            git add "$file"
        fi
    done

    # Run the remaining commands to commit and push
    git commit -m "$2" && \
    git push origin "$3"
}
```

Comment: olala... working! Thanks for your time.

Comment: But checking for file is NOT working, `if [[ ! -e "$1" ]]; then`

Comment: It works fine for me...  That particular expression returns true if the file DOES NOT exist (the `!` in front inverts the expression). You are using Bash, right?

Comment: @AbhishekKamal that test assumes the file is in the current directory, it will fail if you run this from a different directory, for example if you are in a parent directory of where the file is stored.

Comment: Or that you give the full path..

Comment: If I add multiple files (src/ package.json), then it is NOT working. It is adding "package.json" as a commit message

Comment: Which part about *"Make sure that all arguments containing spaces are enclosed in quotes"* is hard to understand? Anyway, I edited for clarity.

Comment: @ArturMeinild the way it's currently given, the function will end up running `git add "src/ package.json any_other_file"`, treating `src/ package.json any_other_file` as a single argument. Maybe a better way would be to have the message and branch name as the first and second arguments, since they are only one argument each, and have the filenames be the remaining arguments.

Comment: Now changed to accommodate multiple files - this wasn't originally clear to me, and expanded the scope of the script quite a bit.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks for your time here ! ❤️

Answer (score 1):

@arturmeinild approach is very good. If you need to keep track of more such alias or script commands, you can create a folder in `/home/$USER/bin` and store the commands in idividual script files.

```
mkdir /home/$USER/bin
cd /home/$USER/bin
touch gc
chmod 755 gc
gedit gc
```

Paste the following contents into the file

```
#!/bin/bash

git add "$1" && \
git commit -m "$2" && \
git push origin "$3"
```

Save andnclose the file. In your `~/.bashrc`, add this line at the end if it is not already there (check for similar path export commands)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/$HOME/bin
```

Now you can use the `gc` commands anywhere. You can extend it to do anything. For example set the command fail if something is wrong in between using `set -e` above the commands.

Also if you sync this folder or create the above command script file in any syncable folder, you will have this command backed up.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is a function as described above

git commands alias also exist in ~/.gitconfig in which you can add in alias section a few shorter command

```
[alias]
ci = commit
co = checkout
st = status -uno

bn = rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

this will allow you to have shorter commands (note I use clearcase like alias ;-) )

```
git add newfile     # not worth for 3 letters command
git ci -am 'feat: added feature blabla'   # note this will commit ALL updated files too
git push <remote-name> $(git bn)
```

you can also have more complex reuse of command in same way e.g

```
# branch owners(last commit) on remote 
bown = for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/remotes/ --format='%(HEAD) %(color:yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) - %(authorname) (%(color:green)%(committerdate:short)%(color:reset))'
l = log --oneline -n 10 --decorate=short
lg = log -n10 --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```